# AMP elements covering other items with absolute positioning

Tags: css, absolute, amp-html, amp-img

I have a basic AMP page with an amp iframe and a few amp images

https://www.freshcottages.com/region/cambridgeshire.htm

When you click the main menu item, say "England", the menu appears behind the AMP iframe and AMP images.

Is there any way to stop this? I've tried playing with **z-index** but not had any success.

If the items are turned into standard iframe and img elements then they work fine so it just looks like its the AMP framework that's throwing it off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative` and a `z-index` value above zero to your `nav` element and that should fix your issue.